# Will each QueueNotification of a push message lead to either a NotificationSent or NotificationFailed

Tags: c#, push, pushsharp

I am new to Push messages and PushSharp.

I have a list of device ids to which I need to send a push notification message. But I do not want my program to wait on them forever. So I have two small questions:

1. Will each call to the `QueueNotification` method of a `PushBroker` object eventually lead to a `NotificationSent` or `NotificationFailed` event?
2. Can I use the `Tag` property of `GcmNotification` and `AppleNotification` objects to store the device id so I will know who the received exactly was?

Answer (score 0):

1. In my app I've always seen a Sent event raised, but this might not always be the case.
2. Yes you can use the tag property to store an identifier for the message, which can be retrieved on the sent/failed events.

I think this [link](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/28) has more detail which might be helpful.

Regards,